# Get data from array in php

Tags: php

How can i get the data from my array $statistics['core.views']. I have tried the doing `<?php echo $statistics['core.views']['label'] ?>` but it returns no data. Please any suggestion or advice please.

```
// Statistics
    $statistics = array();

    // views
    $statistics['core.views'] = array(
      'label' => 'Page Views',
      'today' => Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('core.views', 'day'),
      'total' => Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('core.views'),
    );

    // signups
    $statistics['user.creations'] = array(
      'label' => 'Members',
      'today' => Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('user.creations', 'day'),
      'total' => Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('user.creations'),
    );
```

Comment: write here what you tried

Comment: `<?php echo $statistics['core.views']['label'] ?>`

Comment: [**norepro**](https://3v4l.org/WCQnd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the other array items in variables before placing them in the main array. They are probably breaking the array. For example

```
$today = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('core.views', 'day');
```

then add it to the array like this

```
$statistics['core.views'] = array(
  'label' => 'Page Views',
  'today' => $today,
);
echo $statistics['core.views']['label'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This only could fail, if a method returns an fatal error:

```
Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('statistics', 'core')->getTotal('XXXX', 'day')
```

You can also try to dump this, to see its content

```
var_dump( $statistics )
```

**You should be sure, that there is no error.**
Try to enable your error output, or just take a look into the php `error_log`